# Yourself vs By yourself/On your own

Tags: pronouns, reflexives

I'm confused with this sentence:

> Do they give you the topic or can you choose it [...]

So my book says the *correct* answer is "**yourself**".
Is it *grammatically incorrect* to use "**By yourself/On your own**" in the sentence?

If these two options are both correct, is there any difference between them in this case?

Comment: 'Yourself' sounds more ... adult, professional here. The others have a flavour of children's speech when not referencing a physical aloneness ("Are you on your own up there in the cabin?").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Yourself](https://www.google.com/search?q=yourself%20meaning&sxsrf=AOaemvLeslKfsgl8zT_22c3GE7wLCE3jfg%3A1631013780116&source=hp&ei=lEs3YdGcBOmv5NoPxv6_yAU&iflsig=ALs-wAMAAAAAYTdZpHfDqqzFOTn2GmJ-FRo4gBaWx870&oq=yourself&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYATIFCAAQkQIyBQgAEIAEMgcIABCxAxAKMgUIABCABDIHCAAQsQMQCjIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEOgQIIxAnOhEILhCxAxCDARDHARDRAxCRAjoLCAAQsQMQgwEQkQI6EQguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBENEDOggIABCABBCxAzoICC4QgAQQsQM6DgguEIAEELEDEMcBEK8BOg4ILhCABBCxAxDHARDRAzoTCC4QsQMQgwEQsQMQxwEQ0QMQCjoLCC4QgAQQxwEQowI6BQguEIAEOggIABCxAxCRAjoLCC4QgAQQxwEQrwFQygZYmQ9gzxpoAHAAeACAAZsBiAHZBpIBAzMuNZgBAKABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz)*** stresses that YOU (personally), as opposed to others, can be the agent of that choice.

***[By yourself](https://www.google.com/search?q=by%20yourself%20meaning&sxsrf=AOaemvJRULaMundbW3cU3L-SMTXKc2iluA%3A1631013784660&ei=mEs3YfbbJ9eFhbIP_-WQ8AY&oq=by%20yourself%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIECAAQHjIGCAAQBRAeMgYIABAFEB4yBggAEAUQHjIGCAAQBRAeOgcIIxCwAxAnOgcIABBHELADOgcIABCwAxBDOgcIIxCwAhAnOgYIABAHEB5KBAhBGABQhqkCWKKsAmDNsQJoAXACeACAAUiIAdQBkgEBM5gBAKABAcgBCsABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwj2h4jq3-zyAhXXQkEAHf8yBG4Q4dUDCA4&uact=5)/[on your own](https://www.google.com/search?q=on%20your%20own%20meaning&sxsrf=AOaemvKKElbMaA9I5ibFUVcoOdUQEbdTQA%3A1631013857773&ei=4Us3YYvYLoj1gAbx0Z-IAQ&oq=on%20your%20own%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEAcQHjIFCAAQgAQyBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeOgQIABBDOgkIIxAnEEYQ-QE6CAgAEAgQBxAeSgQIQRgAUJWjAlinsQJgsbsCaABwAngAgAFeiAHuBpIBAjExmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjLzPaM4OzyAhWIOsAKHfHoBxEQ4dUDCA4&uact=5)*** stresses more that you make this choice ***alone, without help from others***.

So although the meanings may slightly overlap, the terms are not interchangeable.

Your sentence is about receiving a given topic as opposed to the possibility  to choose that topic personally (the idea of being helped by others to choose the topic or of choosing this topic together with others is not present in this context).

Comment: "the idea of being helped by others to choose the topic or of choosing this topic together with others is not present in this context". Then shouldn't be the answer "By yourself"?

Comment: Oh, I guess I understand it now. It is just in the example the questioner does not assume that someone will help the answerer with choosing the topic. Right?

Comment: Exactly. It is obvious from the situation that you are supposed to choose the topic **personally**, not **with help from** or **together with** others.

Answer (score 0):

We also use reflexive pronouns to emphasize a person we are referring to. In this sentence, you use yourself without a preposition after the indirect object 'it' to emphasize 'You'.

You can also use 'on your own' as an adverbial phrase modifying the verb 'choose' - it answers the question how are you going to choose.

Using 'by yourself' denotes that you can choose sth alone or w/o the help of others. Neither I see this grammatically incorrect too.

As a recap:

1. yourself can be used for emphasis
2. on your own can be used as a modifier
3. by yourself means without the intervention of other people.